# Expand entrance area

Tags: framing, exterior, remodeling, front-door, addition

My entrance is below photo and it is very tight/small space inside. I would love to expand it "out" to make inside area larger.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Do I frame all the way to the top (hitting the roof) and make a box above the door like so?

   a. If that is the case, how far can I go to ensure some roof overhang?

   b. Is it possible to remove the old wall? What do I look for?

[image]

2. Or should I make a small roof sloping down like below (not touching anything on top):

[image]

Also look like in either case, I have to pour more concrete foundation on both side of the top stair, right?

But please advise if I should stay away from this idea (and why). Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be asking a question about design, which is off-topic as a matter of opinion. If it's something else, please revise to make that more clear.

Comment: You will likely not be able to use the existing concrete stairs as part of the foundation for this. It will probably have to come out.

Comment: @isherwood I modified the question. It's more about framing and clearance code... Not design option.

Comment: @longneck Can you elaborate more on the concrete stair? From the look, it's probably same level as what is in side. If I pour more concrete on left/right side, would it do it?

Comment: Your revisions didn't change much. Code doesn't have anything to say about your design, really, and the overhang question is completely up to you. Your bigger concern is the foundation, which requires full frost footings to locally-required depth.

Answer (score 1):

I like your first idea best. In fact, you could expand the addition to include the area to the left and include an entry closet. (I don’t like the looks of additions “pasted” on.)

By expanding up to the existing roof, you’ll give the entrance a sense of volume and space, AND you’ll have an interior entry chandelier.

Remember, any glass in a door, within 18” of the door or within 18” of the floor needs to be safety glass, (tempered or laminate).

Be sure to check with Building Codes to make sure you’re allowed by zoning ordinances, (i.e.: lot coverage limits, setbacks,etc.)

Comment: Is there a requirement on roof overhang on top of the entrance door? I just want to see how far I can go. Also I just cannot remove the old wall on top of the old door, right? That seems to be supporting the roof...?

Comment: There is no “minimum” overhang requirement at your front door. However, usually there’s about 24” minimum just for convenience: ((i.e.: get your key out in the rain, put a jacket on, etc.) ALSO, yes the exterior wall is a load bearing wall and you’ll need to insure there’s an adequate header where you remove the wall...the roof beam may be adequate.